# Node.js throwing error when trying to reverse resolve ip address

Tags: node.js

So I am trying to reverse resolve the ip address of `nodejs.org` but it is throwing error `Error: getHostByAddr ENOTFOUND 104.20.23.46`.

Here is the code part:

```
const dns = require('dns');

dns.resolve4('nodejs.org', (err, addresses) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(`addresses: ${JSON.stringify(addresses)}`);

  addresses.forEach((a) => {
    dns.reverse(a, (err, hostnames) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(`reverse for ${a}: ${JSON.stringify(hostnames)}`);
    });
  });
});
```

Why isn't the domain name resolving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ host 104.20.23.46
46.23.20.104.in-addr.arpa has no PTR record
```

So there's no name associated with that IP-address, you can't run a reverse lookup on it.

To be complete: you *can* resolve the domain/hostname, you just can't run a reverse lookup on the IP-numbers that the domain/hostname resolves to (it's `dns.reverse()` that's failing, not `dns.resolve4()`).

Comment: Yes I see they are also using Cloudflare service